# How to get request referrer domain? Without subdomain [RAILS]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example:

```
@ref = 'http://sub.domain.com'
URI.parse(@ref).host
```

returns 'sub.domain.com'. How to get 'domain.com' only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a regex to `URI.parse(@ref).host` returning only the domain

```
URI.parse(@ref).host.match(/\w*.com$/)[0]
```

Comment: i am try 'sub.domain.net ' - and get error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. its only for .com - match(/\w*.com$/)[0]

Comment: In that case you must use /\w*.(com|net)$/ in as your regex. Every top-level domain that you want to add use |<domain> inside those parenthesis (com|net|org|io|...) and etc

Comment: if domain is 'do-main.com' - result 'match(/\w*.com$/)[0]' = main.com

Comment: Change it to /^http:\/\/.*\.(.*.com$)/. Take a look in Regex it will be useful when working with text

Comment: Not a universal solution. Also all the .co.uk cases are not considered here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.domain(1)` to get 'domain.com'.

Per the Rails Guides section about [the request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object) , the `request.domain` property takes an optional argument, i.e. `request.domain(n)` returns

> The hostname's first n segments, starting from the right (the TLD).

It's not obvious from this description, but it's actually starting from the dot before the TLD; so given a request object for 'sub.domain.com', `request.domain(0)` would return '.com' and `request.domain(1)` would return 'domain.com'.

Comment: Note that this does not answer the current question about _referrer_ domain, but it's a good answer to *another* question (and the answer I was looking for, in fact) — how to get the root domain of the current request.

Answer (score 0):

To get the domain name you have to use the below

```
request.domain
```

If you use

```
@ref = 'http://sub.domain.com'
URI.parse(@ref).host ====> It will give you host name(Both domain and subdomain)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use request.

```
request.domain
```

Comment: its return not referrer domain

Comment: They are looking for the referrer domain.